# Mantener fija la sección del menú

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer una lista de navegacion en la cual cuando haga click sobre cualquiera de los links me lleve a una parte determinada de la pagina.
Necesito ayuda para lograr qur la lista queda en la izquierda mientras que todo lo que incluye al body se ubique a su derecha (de la lista).
Con este codigo logro que los links funcionen pero lo que nose como lograr es como es que se ubiquen a la izqueirda de la pagina mientras que el resto del body quede a la derecha de ellos (no agregue el resto del codigo porque es muy largo)

El codigo HTML que tengo es este:

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ejercicio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1>Gestion de Series</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>   
            <a href ="#" class="clase1"> Series</a>
            <br>
            <a href ="#" class="clase2"> Opiniones</a>
            <br>
            <a href ="#" class="clase3"> Estadisticas</a>
        </nav>
```

El codigo CSS es este:

```
.clase1{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,186,3,0), rgba(252, 186, 3, 1));
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000
}
  
.clase2{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(209,64,36,0), rgba(209, 64, 36, 1));
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000
}

.clase3{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(156,9,26,0), rgba(156, 9, 26, 1));
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000
}
```

Comment: acabo de editar la publicacion esperando que se pueda entender mejor mi problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes proceder de la siguiente forma:

Tener una estructura HTML como la siguiente:

- Tu menú de navegación mantenlo dentro del `nav`
- Las secciones a las que vas a navegar colócalas dentro de una etiqueta `section`

Lo anterior de manera inicial nos dejará el bloque del menú encima del bloque de las secciones, para solventar esto hacemos lo siguiente:

- Como deseamos que el menú este a la izquierda y permanezca fijo, le damos las siguientes propiedades:

  ```
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  ```

Lo anterior lo hacemos para que el elemento (*el menú que existe dentro del `nav`*) no sea afectado por el movimiento del scroll<sup>1</sup>

- Sin embargo lo anterior genera el problema que tu menú queda fuera del flujo de los nodos de la página y se vería *amontado* texto y menú, para solventar eso; hacemos lo siguiente:

  ```
  #secciones {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
  ```

Esta medida es un tanto a modo pero nos ayuda a indicar un separamiento del lado izquierdo de la sección de contenidos y evitar que queden como ya mencionaba

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      .menu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
      }
      #secciones {
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-list__element">
          <a href="#inicio">
            Inicio
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-list__element">
          <a href="#medio">
            Medio
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-list__element">
          <a href="#fin">
            Fin
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="secciones">
      <p class="secciones-parrafo" id="inicio">
        <p>El inicio</p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus nam cum possimus maxime animi nemo pariatur ipsa, incidunt sit corporis explicabo quae provident autem sapiente labore commodi nobis facere magni.</span>
        <span>Sit nihil voluptatum autem tenetur inventore asperiores deserunt magni impedit totam non quas, numquam vitae molestias distinctio velit, vel, optio alias minus error soluta repellat quae qui aliquid vero debitis.</span>
        <span>Veniam quod tempore, ipsum sed. Id ratione adipisci facere et debitis, explicabo nostrum at repudiandae ipsam molestias doloribus saepe perferendis fugit, quam quae dolor praesentium! Modi cupiditate qui, vel iusto.</span>
      </p>
      <p class="secciones-parrafo" id="medio">
        <p>El medio</p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque magnam corrupti atque, blanditiis repellendus commodi adipisci, consequuntur maxime rem error nesciunt debitis ullam. Hic velit quibusdam, repudiandae consequuntur explicabo nostrum.</span>
        <span>Mollitia et, sit? Placeat aspernatur nam fugiat rerum corporis odit sunt temporibus nesciunt praesentium, quae ex optio perspiciatis, earum, natus qui vero aut, repellendus officiis. Earum aut, repellat officiis nostrum.</span>
        <span>Sint cumque consectetur quidem labore cum consequuntur ut officia similique repellat, incidunt quia laboriosam unde suscipit? Incidunt illo nihil dicta consectetur, impedit, officia necessitatibus tempora reprehenderit, maiores obcaecati doloribus, iste.</span>
      </p>
      <p class="secciones-parrafo" id="fin">
        <p>El final</p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit earum dolor quos eveniet quae repudiandae aspernatur at, ea fuga pariatur veritatis nemo nam doloribus est mollitia sequi culpa quia praesentium.</span>
        <span>Neque nihil, placeat odio nemo eum iusto necessitatibus assumenda molestiae quos nulla, dicta quibusdam, repellendus? Illo rem quas voluptas error consequuntur at nulla possimus, expedita unde atque, necessitatibus ab, nostrum!</span>
        <span>Possimus harum provident natus laboriosam dolores soluta, id nulla voluptatem, architecto aspernatur! Quod, illum, magni! Voluptas vero quos ipsa ipsam atque est, odit explicabo dicta voluptate aspernatur amet, autem sint.</span>
      </p>
    </section>
```

*Aclaración*

El ejemplo no esta estilizado y seguro puede ser mejorado notablemente, es solo para ilustrar la solución propuesta

**Referencia**

- <sup>1</sup> [Posicionamiento en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: por alguna razon la lista de navegacion con el scroll se mueve a pesar de que use position: fixed;

Comment: Revisa si tu css no tiene alguna otra regla que anule el comportamiento que defino en mi respuesta, tal vez algún framework, etc